# Override Twitter4j Logging with Logback in Scala

Tags: scala, slf4j, logback, twitter4j

I am using twitter4j library in Scala where I am unable to override the logging properties.

Can you tell me how to override the Twitter4j.LoggerFactory with Logback and how to change the status level to ERROR in Scala

https://github.com/yusuke/twitter4j/blob/master/twitter4j-core/src/internal-logging/java/twitter4j/Logger.java

I tried override SLF4J with Logback but it is not working.

```
System.setProperty("twitter4j.loggerFactor","twitter4j.SLF4JLogger")

abstract class SLF4JLoggerFactory extends twitter4j.LoggerFactory {
  @Override def getLogger(clazz:Class[_]) = {
    import ch.qos.logback.classic.Level
    val a = org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger("id")
      .asInstanceOf[ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger]
    a.setLevel(Level.ERROR)
    a.asInstanceOf[twitter4j.Logger]
  }
}
```